# How to set a custom font size on a widget that adapts accordingly after an application font size change?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using Qt4 (I know), and have a custom widget that sets a bold font, with a point size that is 1.5 times the point size of the application font. This works without problems.

The problem now is that in case the application font size is changed, the widget's font size is not updated accordingly (as expected). My initial though was to do something along the following lines:

```
void MyCustomWidget::changeEvent(QEvent* e)
{
  if (e->type() == QEvent::FontChange)
  {
     setFont(boldAndBigFont());
  }
  return QWidget::changeEvent(e);
}
```

This does not work, since the `setFont()` call will trigger a `FontChange` event resulting in endless calls to the change event handler. I noticed there is also `ApplicationFontChange`, which is promising, however that event is not delivered to my custom widget (I verified using an event listener). Looking at the Qt code, the code responsible for propagating the `ApplicationFontChange` event will only deliver this event to a few select widgets (the main window for example).

So my question is; how to solve this in a nice way? One limitation I have is that I cannot use style sheets.

My current solution leans towards a custom font change event, fired from the main window after receiving `ApplicationFontChange`, but surely, I cannot be the first person to have this problem...?

*Update*: I found that calling `QApplication::setFont(bigAndBoldFont(), "MyCustomWidget");` works as well. I do not particularly like it since I would rather keep this styling behavior tied to the implementation of the custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for Qt4 but the following `changeEvent` implementation appears to work as expected with Qt5...

```
virtual void changeEvent (QEvent *event) override
  {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::FontChange) {

      /*
       * Run the default handler for the event.
       */
      super::changeEvent(event);

      /*
       * Now get the application font and create the desired font based on
       * that.
       */
      auto app_font = qApp->font();
      auto desired_font = QFont(app_font.family(), 1.5 * app_font.pointSize(), QFont::Bold);

      /*
       * If the font we now have is the desired font then fine, otherwise
       * set it.
       */
      if (font() != desired_font) {
        setFont(desired_font);
      }
      event->accept();
    }
    super::changeEvent(event);
  }
```

Comment: I tried your implementation. With Qt4, the font change event is received once. Then, as soon as a custom font is set for the widget, the widget will no longer receiver `FontChange` events when modifying the application font through `QApplication::setFont()`. I'll try to repro it with a simpler application, that I can also build against Qt5.

Comment: It has to be a bug somewhere in Qt4 to determine whether a font really changed (or something like that). If I only modify the font boldness, not the point size, the events keep coming...great. I think I'll stick with my custom event that I fire from the one point in the application where the global font size is modified. It's good enough for now and prevents having to dig through the Qt code and bug tracker to see where the problem is.

Comment: You're correct about only receiving the `FontChange` notification once -- it hadn't occurred to me that intercepting/processing the first event would prevent further events.